# Passing array as from Parent to Child and getting back a filtered array in Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Parent component and a Child component.

I am passing an Array from Parent to Child. I want the array to be filtered in the Child and that can be returned back to Parent.

After filtering in Child, it should return a filtered array.

**Parent**

```
const Parent = () =>{

const todoData = [
        {id:0,todoname:"Study",todotoday:"Completing CSS today"},
        {id:1,todoname:"Coding",todotoday:"Leetcode 2 Problems"}
    ];
     const [myArray,setmyArray] = useState(todoData);

<div className="todomain">
    {
         myArray.map((obj)=>{
          return ( <div className="todobox" key={obj.id}>
          <div className="checkcont">
           <img src={check} alt="Check" className='chkbtn btn'/>
          </div>
            <h2 className="head" >Todo: {obj.todoname}</h2>
            <h3 className="todocont">{obj.todotoday}</h3>
            <div className="todoboxbtn">
             <Child todoList = {todoData} />
            </div>
            </div> )
        })
      }
      </div>

}
```

**Child**

```
const Child = ({todoData}) =>{
 onst [myArray,setmyArray] = useState(todoData);

    const removeElm = (id) =>{
        const myNewArray = myArray.filter((currElm)=>{
            return currElm.id !== id;
        })

        setmyArray(myNewArray);
    }

  return (
    <div className="todoicon">
    {
        myArray.map((obj)=>{
   return ( <div className='todobtn' key={obj.props.id}>
    <img src={del} alt="Delete" className='deleteBtn btn' onClick={() => removeElm(obj.props.id)}/>
    </div>)
        })
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Expected:

In the Child component, there is a delete button, which on click should delete that particular Array element and send back the updated array to Parent.

**It is giving the below output**

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaiHZ.png)

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: child should return me a filtered array

Comment: Please paste an example of input and output in your question.

Comment: Have updated the expected result , please refer

Comment: You should be passing state handlers down from the parent. And setting state from props is an anti-pattern for this very reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to change the state of your parent component when the user deletes an item from your TODO list, then you can simply pass the setter to your child component.

In this way you can call your component like this:

```
<Child todoList = {todoData} changeToDo={setmyArray}/>
```

And update your child component like this:

```
const Child = ({todoData, changeToDo}) =>{
     const removeElm = (id) =>{
         changeTodo(myArray.filter((currElm)=>{
             return currElm.id !== id;
         }))
     }

   return (
     <div className="todoicon">
     {
         todoData.map((obj)=>{
            return ( 
               <div className='todobtn' key={obj.id}>
                   <img src={del} alt="Delete" className='deleteBtn btn' onClick={() => removeElm(obj.id)}/>
               </div>
            )
         })
     }
     </div>
   )
}
```

Note that saving the Todo in a state of your child component is not necessary. When you go to update the state of the parent component, a re-render will be performed and your child will have its props updated

**EDIT** The behavior you expect is not the one that will be rendered. Indeed, you iterate with `map` in the parent component and in the child component.
Since the child component apparently only serves to display an image allowing the element to be deleted, you don't need to pass the entire TODOList to it. You could directly pass it a `onClick` function in props, and put it on your image.

Your parent component should be like this :

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Child } from './test2';

const todoData = [
  { id: 0, todoname: 'Study', todotoday: 'Completing CSS today' },
  { id: 1, todoname: 'Coding', todotoday: 'Leetcode 2 Problems' },
];

const Parent = () => {
  const [myArray, setmyArray] = useState(todoData);

  const removeElm = (id) => {
    const myNewArray = myArray.filter((currElm) => {
      return currElm.id !== id;
    });

    setmyArray(myNewArray);
  };

  return (
    <div className="todomain">
      {myArray.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <div className="todobox" key={obj.id}>
            <div className="checkcont">
              <img src={check} alt="Check" className="chkbtn btn" />
            </div>
            <h2 className="head">Todo: {obj.todoname}</h2>
            <h3 className="todocont">{obj.todotoday}</h3>
            <div className="todoboxbtn">
              <Child onDelete={() => removeElm(obj.id)} />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And you child component like this :

```
export const Child = ({ onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <div className="todoicon">
      <div className="todobtn">
        <img
          src={del}
          alt="Delete"
          className="deleteBtn btn"
          onClick={onDelete}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: But there are two Delete button rendering in one Array element due to mapping, how can i solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but it seems to me that ```key={obj.props.id}``` is a little strange. Wouldn't that be ```obj.id```?

Comment: Yaa used obj.id ,  but still mapping two times for one Array Element

Comment: Do you have 4 images displayed?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw. This is normal since you are doing a map in the parent component AND in the child component. So, you should leave that of the parent component, and adapt the code of the child

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Got Your Answer its running, but what if there are two buttons having different Function in child component

Comment: You can give more props in you Child Component. Besides you should rename it, for a more explicit name such as ```DeleteBtnContainer```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a new state in the parent and pass its setter function as a prop to the child and set the value using this setter function.

Parent

```
const Parent = () =>{

    const todoData = [
        {id:0,todoname:"Study",todotoday:"Completing CSS today"},
        {id:1,todoname:"Coding",todotoday:"Leetcode 2 Problems"}
    ];
     const [myArray,setmyArray] = useState(todoData);
     const [filteredArray, setFilteredArray] = useState([]);//add this state

    <div className="todomain">
    {
         myArray.map((obj)=>{
          return ( <div className="todobox" key={obj.id}>
          <div className="checkcont">
           <img src={check} alt="Check" className='chkbtn btn'/>
          </div>
            <h2 className="head" >Todo: {obj.todoname}</h2>
            <h3 className="todocont">{obj.todotoday}</h3>
            <div className="todoboxbtn">
             <Child todoList = {todoData} setFilteredArray={setFilteredArray} />
            </div>
            </div> )
        })
      }
      {/* You can map filteredArray*/}
      </div>

}
```

Child

```
const Child = ({todoList, setFilteredArray}) =>{//also your todoData prop name is todoList
    const [myArray,setmyArray] = useState(todoData);

    const removeElm = (id) =>{
        const myNewArray = myArray.filter((currElm)=>{
            return currElm.id !== id;
        })

        setmyArray(myNewArray);
        setFilteredArray(myNewArray);
    }

  return (
    <div className="todoicon">
    {
        myArray.map((obj)=>{
   return ( <div className='todobtn' key={obj.props.id}>
    <img src={del} alt="Delete" className='deleteBtn btn' onClick={() => removeElm(obj.props.id)}/>
    </div>)
        })
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Getting This Error---->  Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at TodoIcon (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:462:23)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:21540:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24826:17)

Comment: Did you change todoData to todoList in child props as you are passing todoList as a prop to child. Please check.

Comment: Yes changed and its working. But there are two Delete button rendering in one Array element due to mapping, how can i solve it?

Comment: You need to run map only once.